# Swift: add custom view inside CALayer

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I'm trying to add a custom view inside a CALayer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBs2H.png

And I want to put inside some buttons and labels, but I'm afraid I'm not able to do it. I make the CALabel like this:

```
func addRectangleToLayer(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, layer: CALayer, index: UInt32 ) {
    var sublayer = CALayer()
    sublayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    sublayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
    sublayer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    sublayer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    sublayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
    sublayer.cornerRadius = 12.0;
    sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    sublayer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
    sublayer.borderWidth = 0.5;

    //An example
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "LOREN"
    sublayer.contents = label

    layer.insertSublayer(sublayer, atIndex: index)
}
```

Is it possible to do what I want to?

Thanks a lot and excuse me for my english level

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you create a `UIView`, you'll have access to its `layer` property for this purpose:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "LOREN"
var sublayer = label.layer;

// .. the rest of your layer initialization
sublayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
sublayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
sublayer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
sublayer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
sublayer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
sublayer.cornerRadius = 12.0;
sublayer.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
sublayer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
sublayer.borderWidth = 0.5;
// .. ended original source initialization

layer.insertSublayer(sublayer, atIndex: index)
```

Comment: This don't work for me. I decelerate the label, set a text, extract the layer, add this labelLayer to the CALayer and then I insert the CALayer into the main layer. Any help?

Comment: Why are you setting `labelLayer.contents = "HOLA"`? This would replace the contents of your layer (i.e., the layer's CGImage) with a string.

Comment: I want to add only a text now inside the CALayer just for trying. How I add only a label or more than one View?

Comment: In order to add text to the screen, it must be associated with something that can render it. The most common way in iOS is to use a `UILabel`. If you really must use a `CALayer` instead of a `UIView`, take the `CALayer` from within the `UILabel`. If you really can't do that, you can draw text directly using the `CTLineDraw()` method. If `UILabel` does not solve your question, you need to clarify exactly what it is you are trying to do and why `UILabel` will not suffice.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your time and I want to apologize about my english. I want to add things, such as labels, buttons inside something like that, that is a CALayer [(see this image)](http://puu.sh/cEh1R/c80dd0e2f3.png). I'm on the right way?

Comment: You can modify the properties of a `UIView` layer instead of creating a `CALayer` directly. This is what I had intended with my original answer to you.

Comment: Thats awesome! And for including text on it?

Comment: Hi, great answer. What if I want to add another layer to this existing view? How can I do that?